# How to save the current SPI settings with out have a global variable keeping track?

Tags: programming, spi

I am making a function for one of my devices, my device needs a particular SPI setting. I was hoping to save the current setting of the SPI class into some variable, load in the required setting, do a transfer, and after that load back the old setting.

I know there is an object for the SPISettings, but i dont know how to pull the current settings without me having to create a global variable that keeps track of it.

```
void sendSPI(){
 SPISettings oldSettings = ??? ;   //save old SPI Settings
 SPISettings mySettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0);

 digitalWrite(CSPIN,LOW);
 SPI.beginTransaction(mySettings); //load in new SPI Settings
 SPI.transfer(0x0);
 digitalWrite(CSPIN,HIGH);

 SPI.beginTransaction(mySettings); //Revert to old SPI Settings
}
```

Comment: What about trying [static](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/)?

Comment: @st2000 the problem is i do not know the function for access the current settings

Comment: every library which uses SPI should start the transaction with the setting for the specific device. so you don't have to restore the settings. what are your other devices?

Comment: I'm going to assume you know what you want (but this may be a case where there are better ways to do what you want in C++ when considering the problem from a higher level perspective). In your class, write a method that will return ("expose") the desired variables.  Then, each time you instantiate your class, call those functions to return the desired values.

Comment: "every library which uses SPI should start the transaction with the setting for the specific device. ... "  I've had cases @Juraj where the I2C device was "unconventional" and had to use unusual settings.  But have to admit, I've never tried mixing these w/more conventional I2C devices on the same bus.

Comment: @st2000 "Once you have your SPI parameters, use SPI.beginTransaction() to begin using the SPI port." from https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/communication/spi?#serial-peripheral-interface-spi

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.h#L203 you can make a backup for SPSR and SPCR (but it kinda expects you are using clasic AVR Arduino)

Comment: @Juraj im using adafruit libraries, and they have their own spi/i2c classes kind of a rats nest, im just making sure i wont inadvertently bug out their libraries. It also assures that my function is compatible with libraries not following conventions

Comment: `How to save the current SPI settings with out have a global variable keeping track?` is a somewhat misleading question because you said  `i do not know the function for access the current settings` ... when you figure out how to read the current settings, then save them in EEPROM

Comment: the adafruit libraries have software (bit-banging) SPI as an option, but you don't use software SPI pins for multiple devices. If you use hardware SPI they relay on the SPI library and use beginTransaction